# What is the term for the quantity (high price minus low price) for a stock?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, trading-volume

I believe my professor called this **variant price**, but I am not certain.  Is there a standard term?

Comment: I think you're going to need to add more detail to get an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is known as the `range` or the `price spread` of the stock. You can read more about it here http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/range.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here… How about Daily Median price?

StockCharts provides a similar value they call VWAP. Which stands for [**Volume-Weighted Average Price**](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?st=vwap&id=chart_school:technical_indicators:vwap_intraday). I believe it is a better 'average' for the day (click on link).

Comment: Hi Jack, I think that he had a dash, and did not mean for you to think that was a minus sign. I think what he wants is just called intraday range. Thoughts?

Comment: Interesting idea Joe. The high daily price minus the low daily price would yeald the median price for the day. But the high and the low prices taken as a pair would define the daily range. Still, I believe that the best way to correlate volume with the median price is by using the VWAP. @Brick, please do add detail to clarify.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: It is actually a minus sign I mean. I am finding a term that can express the value of (High Price - Low Price). Actually It is a max high price and min price among the intraday period.

Comment: To be clear, if a stock traded with low $80 and high $82, you want $2?

Comment: Insightful question Joe. A median would be (high_value - low_value) + low value. So high_value - low_value would be a range, not any kind of average. What benefit does a range provide? To make comparison to other securities I would think that you would want to divide the range by some kind of average. A security with a high of 82 and low of 80 would have a range of 2. Then we could divide the range by the median to get a 'range quotient' of approx. 2.47%.

Comment: @JackSwayzeSr (High-Low)+Low is not the median, it's just the High again. Also, average does not = median. Volume-Weighted **Average** Price does not have anything to do with median price.

Comment: @Chris ; yeah I was in a rush, trying to state the formula by memory, and I got it wrong. ((H-L)/2) + L is the correct formula, I believe.  Take a high of 85, and a low of 81. 85-81=4. 4/2=2. 2+81=83. 83 would be the median. . . . There are three kinds of average: mean, median, and mode. When most people say 'average'  they mean the mean. But mode and median are also averages.. . .  The original post was about relating the volume to H-L.  I just stated my opinion that the Volume Weighted Average Price is the best way to accomplish integrating the volume into a price.